# Create Temp XML File With ActionScript

Tags: xml, actionscript

I would like to locally save an XML file with ActionScript, as a temp file, if at all possible. I've read all about how AS won't let you do this without dialogs (and I understand the security concerns), but surely there must be some sort of temp option? I need to dynamically generate some XML to pass to another swf using `URLVariables` (I have no control over this part). Right now, I can only pass in previously created XML files.

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.data_file = "us/data.xml"; //data.xml is static/already created
urlReq.data = variables;
ldr.load(urlReq);
```

I would like to replace `us/data.xml` with xml I've created.

Comment: are you passing the actual xml file, or just the link to the xml file? It seems like it's just the link

Comment: Right now it's a path to a local xml file stored on disk. The problem arises in that I modify the XML on the fly from ActionScript and now need to figure out how to pass that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the XML object directly through the `URLRequest` or the `URLVariables` object. Something like:

```
var x:XML = ...;

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest( url )
req.data = xml;
ldr.load( urlReq );
```

If the xml is large, then you can compress it with a `ByteArray`:

```
var x:XML = ...;
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
bytes.writeUTFBytes( x );
bytes.compress();

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest( url )
req.data = bytes;
ldr.load( urlReq );
```

If you have a problem, you might need to encode it with Base64, in which case, you can use this lib: http://jpauclair.net/2010/01/09/base64-optimized-as3-lib/

Also as some alternatives, have you looked at `LocalConnection`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html or `SharedObject.getRemote()` (requires Flash Media Server): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getRemote()

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I'm working with the swf available from [here](http://backspace.com/mapapp/us/us.zip). I won't say I know much about AS, but it seems to me that my swf wants a file, and it's expecting to open a file and process it. Thus, passing the raw data is not what it is looking for.

Comment: If you don't have access to the other SWF (as in to change it to accept either an address or an XML object), then the only other way you can get around it is to pass by a server script. As in, pass your XML to PHP, get it to save the file (or overwrite the original), then send the second flash file the name of the file. You'll have to track the deleting of the files yourself as well (as Flash can't delete system files)

Comment: Any hints on how to pass XML from SWF to PHP?

Comment: Check out AMFPHP: http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/. It lets you communicate easily between AS3 and PHP (it's possible to do it without this, it's just that this is easier). Call a function and pass the XML or ByteArray to PHP, then get the PHP to save it. There's tons of tutorials on saving files in PHP. This one is for .txt files, but you get the idea: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/69055-how-to-save-a-txt-file-to-a-server-using-php-code/